# Setting other font than system in WatchKit (Apple Watch)

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have one Apple Watch app that is using Menlo Bold font for label.

In first version of Xcode that supported watchkit I was able to change font of label in storyboard to Menlo Bold 36 and everything was working fine.

In curent version (Xcode 6.2) that is not possible any more, so I found this tutorial on how to set custom font in Apple Watch, http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/53710/how-do-i-use-custom-fonts-in-my-apple-watch-app/

I this tutorial I found this code:

```
func printFonts() {
    let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames()
    for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
        println("------------------------------")
        println("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
        let names = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName as String)
        println("Font Names = [\(names)]")
    }
}
```

This code print available fonts.
It is used to see why is the name of the font that you have added.

At this stage I have not added any custom font, but I run this function just to see what font are available on Apple Watch by default.
After running this I found:

```
/* lot of fonts before */
------------------------------
Font Family Name = [Menlo]
Font Names = [[Menlo-BoldItalic, Menlo-Regular, Menlo-Bold, Menlo-Italic]]
------------------------------
/* lot of fonts after */
```

It look like that my Menlo-Bold is available on Apple Watch, but I just can not select it in StoryBoard.

So , I was think this is very good, I do not need to add font I will just use it.

This is my code:

```
    // must maee attributed text
    let attributedTextForHour = NSAttributedString(
        string: "IS IT WORKING",
        attributes: NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "Menlo-Bold", size: 36)!, forKey:NSFontAttributeName))

    // with atributex text
    mylabel.setAttributedText(attributedTextForHour)
```

When I run this code in simulator, font of the label is not changed.
And here are some other strange things:

- in debugger, when I set break point on `mylabel.setAttributedText(attributedTextForHour)` and do quick look on `attributedTextForHour` it is showed in correct font.

So in debugger it is fine, but on simulator it is not.

So how to fix this ?

I do not have Apple Watch, so I can see what is happening on real device.

So, I do no know is there some problem in my code or this is bug form Apple.

If somebody can test this on the is computer and report results, that will be useful also.

Maybe whole problem is because I have not added Menlo Bold font from outside and I am using what printFont() function has shown.
So if anybody know where I can download Menlo Bold font, please provide link, so that I can test that also.

Answer (score 3):

I manage to solve this problem, so I am posting for future generations.

There are few things that I have learned from this (after 3h of work)

- Font that are by default printed by `printFonts()` they look-like that are available but they are not.
- you can add your *.otf font by following http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/53710/how-do-i-use-custom-fonts-in-my-apple-watch-app/ and then you can just select it in Storybord by custom font, so you do not need to make NSAttributedString

If you want to add font that is already printed in `printFonts()` that things become complicated.

You can not add it by same name, so you must add it with different name, I called it Menlo-Bold-My.otf, and you must change some ID of font.
So Menlo-Bold-My.otf is same as Menlo-Bold.otf from Apple.

For converting, manipulating fonts I used program http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/